# Writing multiple values in different columns in a csv file in R

Tags: file, r, csv

Can anyone help me with this:
I have calculated 2 different values: standard deviation and z-scores.

I'm trying to figure out how to write these into a csv file in different columns in R. I have about 90 different standard deviation values and 90 zscore values.
So I want all my standard deviation values in 1 column and all my z-scores in the 2nd column. I also want to label the column with standard deviation and z-score.

Right now I'm calculating and writing them into separate files in a loop like this:

```
write.table(st_dev, file="st_dev.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
write.table(z_score, file="z.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

Edit:

```
for(i in 1:130)
 {
 y=test3[i,3:52]
 z=as.numeric(y)
 average = mean(z)
 st_dev = sd(z)
 dfrm <- data.frame(average=average, st_dev=st_dev)
 write.table(dfrm, file="av_st.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, append=TRUE)
}
```

How can I have the column headers just once at the top instead of printing it for each value in the csv file? Thanks

Comment: Since you're using `append=TRUE` the two answers would need that statement too.  However, its much faster to assign the two values to a `data.frame` within the loop and only write to a file once.  If you post more of your looping code (potentially in another question) I'm sure you could speed up the write step dramatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a dataframe and the write it.

```
y=test3[1,3:52]
 z=as.numeric(y) 
average = mean(z) 
st_dev = sd(z) }
 dfrm <- data.frame(average = average, st_dev = st_dev)
write.table(dfrm, file="z_st.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)

for(i in 2:130) { y=test3[i,3:52]
 z=as.numeric(y) 
average = mean(z) 
st_dev = sd(z) }
 dfrm <- data.frame(average = average, st_dev = st_dev)
write.table(dfrm, file="z_st.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)}
```

Comment: When I am trying to do it this way it gives me the following warning:In write.table(dfrm, file = "z_st.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE,  ... :  appending column names to file. Should I ignore this warning? Also the file has 2 columns like I wanted but for each standard deviation and zscore value it writes the column names in the file because I am calculating values in the loop. How can I put the column names at the top only?Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand either this comment or the one above by Justin. I am not using append =TRUE and there should be only one header. If your data consists of two separate groups and you are going to write these separately,  then you need to make that clear in the question. You will then need a third column to be the group identifier.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
write.table(cbind(st_dev,z_score), 
file="whatever.csv",row.names=F,col.names=c('st_dev','z_score'))
```